# Why we need to do both when justify an array is empty?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, given an array in java : `nums`
When we justify whether `nums` is empty or not, we need to do-

```
if(nums == null || nums.length == 0)
```

instead of just

```
if(nums.length == 0)
```

why?

Comment: Because there is a difference between the array not existing and the array having no elements.

Comment: To allow caller to pass a `null` value instead of having to create a 0-size array, if there is no data to be passed.

Comment: why don't you set `nums = null` and try both and see what you get?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that `nums` isn't undefined first, otherwise attempting to reference a property from an undefined or null object will result in a [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Additionally, each of the pieces of code does two completely different things and your case, either would be sufficient as indicating that you shouldn't "do something" with the array :

```
nums == null      // This checks if your array exists
nums.length == 0  // This checks if your array has no elements
```

Comment: `null` and "undefined" is not the same thing. Actually, Java doesn't use that term. It can be "undeclared" (causing compile error), or "unassigned" (also compile error), but a reference value of `null` is still a well-defined value.

Comment: That's a good point @Andreas. It's been quite some time since I've written any Java. Feel free to edit the answer if you feel you can make it a bit more "Java-accurate".

Answer (score 0):

Consider this set of methods:

```
public void breakEverything() {
    MyClass[] bob;
    // pass a null object to iterateArray
    iterateArray(bob);
}

public void dontBreakStuff() {
    MyClass[] bob = new MyClass[0];
    // pass an array of length 0 to iterateArray
    iterateArray(bob);
}

public void iterateArray(int[] arr) {
    for (int i == 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        doSomethingWith(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

There's actually a couple things going on here:

In the case of the `breakEverything()` method - you're passing a null reference into the `iterateArray()` method.  That is the argument `arr` is null, and thus calling any methods or accessing any variables on that argument will throw an NPE.  You protect against this by including the check:

```
if (arr == null) {
    return;
}
```

There's a second problem here with your question though:

> When we justify whether nums is empty or not, we need to do if(nums ==
>   null || nums.length == 0) instead of just if(nums.length == 0)

The problem here is that `MyClass[].length()` returns the *allocated capacity of the array*, it doesn't' actually return the number of elements you've placed in the array - that is it's not counting the number of non null indicies.  You may be thinking of `ArrayList.size()` - which does actually count the number of elements in the List, rather than the allocated space (this is because ArrayList's can grow and shrink in size, where as a primitive array cannot).

Answer (score 0):

If an array is not initialized with data i.e

```
int[] nums=null;
if(nums.length==0){}
```

gives you **NullPointerException** - because, you are trying to access information which does not exist

If you declared but not initialized the array `nums`

```
int[] nums ;
if(nums==null || nums.length==0){}
```

gives you **compilation error** - because you are not initialized and trying to access it

In short `nums==null` is a **null check**